# How to make a div that was created on the web application appear at the top left corner of parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have web application that allows users to create rectangles which are divs.The issue now is that i want the the created divs to always be at the top left corner of its parent container but what i get is the first div will be at the corner and the subsequently created divs will appear below it.I believe its because my **CSS position is relative**.But i cant use position absolute as the **position has to be relative to make the rectangles draggable**.

I have already tried using margin-top:0px and vertical-align:top but it did not work.Is there another way to have the same effect as position:absolute?

**CSS:**

```
 .box {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px;
top: 0px;
max-height: inherit;
max-width: inherit;
cursor: move;
vertical-align: top;
}
#boxContain{
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 600px;
z-index: 900;
}
```

The boxes should overlap one another and be at the top left corner of the parent instead of having one below another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like all of the `<div>`'s are ending up in the same parent container. Can you adjust your code so that each `<div>` gets it's own container? Otherwise, they cannot possibly all end up in one desired spot.

Comment: There will be a minor bug if i do it this way.For example,if i create multiple boxes,only the one on top will be draggable. But if i create one,move it,then create another one,both are draggable.But this is not a good UI...

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution for this would be to use `position`, but if not using it is a constraint, one solution would be to set a negative `margin-top` on your `.box` elements equal to the height of the element, with an equivalent positive `padding-top` on their containing element.

In the following example, three boxes all sit on top of each other:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```